# Android SQLITE search column

Tags: android, sql, search

I'm trying to search a database for a string. Im very new to SQLite so please excuse my ignorance
I setup the call as follows

```
public void GetContact() {
    //---get a contact---
    EditText mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextnum);
    mEdit.setText("A000021");
   db.open();
   Cursor c = db.getAsset(mEdit.getText());
   if (c.moveToFirst())        
    DisplayContact(c);
   else
   Toast.makeText(this, "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   db.close();
}
```

This fills a edittext with the string "A000021" and then runs the procedure in the DB helper "getAsset" using the contents of the edittext as the search string

The get Asset procedure is as follows

```
public Cursor getAsset(Editable strname) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL,KEY_FLOOR,KEY_ROOMID,KEY_SCHOOLID,KEY_CONDITION,KEY_ASSETNUMBER,KEY_ASSETCATEGORY,KEY_ASSETTYPE,KEY_ADDITIONAL,KEY_MANUFACTURER,KEY_TYPE,KEY_SERIAL,KEY_INFO,KEY_QUANTITY,KEY_COMMENTS,KEY_INSTALL,KEY_VERIFIED}, KEY_ASSETNUMBER + "=" + strname, null,null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

when I run its says

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: A000021 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, SITE, BUILDING, FLOOR, ROOMID, SCHOOLID, CONDITION, ASSETNUMBER, ASSETCATEGORY, ASSETTYPE, ADDITIONAL, MANUFACTURER, TYPEMODEL, SERIALNUMBER, INFORMATION, QUANTITY, COMMENTS, INSTALLDATE, VERIFIED FROM contacts WHERE ASSETNUMBER=A000021
```

The column is called ASSETNUMBER it is a text column and im looking to return the record that has an assetnumber of A000021

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code that you use for creating the table?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) function

```
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL,KEY_FLOOR,KEY_ROOMID,KEY_SCHOOLID,KEY_CONDITION,KEY_ASSETNUMBER,KEY_ASSETCATEGORY,KEY_ASSETTYPE,KEY_ADDITIONAL,KEY_MANUFACTURER,KEY_TYPE,KEY_SERIAL,KEY_INFO,KEY_QUANTITY,KEY_COMMENTS,KEY_INSTALL,KEY_VERIFIED}, KEY_ASSETNUMBER + " like '" + strname+"' ", null,null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks so much though it was something simple my original query was missing the single quotes